# 'this' used as a parameter in callback declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

`FileReader` has the following TypeScript signature for its `onerror` callback in lib.dom.d.ts

```
onerror: ((this: FileReader, ev: ProgressEvent) => any) | null;
```

Can someone point me to why the correct usage omits it:

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onerror = (error: ProgressEvent) => reject(error); // rejecting a promise - snipped for brevity
```

I would like to better understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That declaration indicates what `this` inside that function must refer to. In this case, a `FileReader` instance.

You don't need to pass that value, because it's inferred, as you're assigning that function to a property of a `FileReader` object. It forces you to only call that function as a method of `FileReader`.

That way, the function must always be called safely, and using `this` inside it is safe:

```
function handleError(error) {
   console.log(this.readyState);
}
```

Now, if you assign this function to `onerror`, when `onerror` is called, `this` will have a valid value for `this`.

But that function is a normal function and you could do:

```
handleError(error);
```

This, in JavaScript, would cause a runtime error (`this` is `undefined`).

So, with only that annotation, the TypeScript compiler will protest here, forcing you to call the function only in the context of a `FileReader` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript supports `this parameters` in callbacks. `this parameters` are fake parameters that come first in the parameter list of a function. Passing the `this` parameter allows typescript to know the explicit type of `this`.

See http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters for more info.